# seaborn mixing of plots

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm having trouble creating this plot in spyder:

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
diamonds= sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
df=diamonds.copy()
cut_Kategoriler=["Fair","Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal"]
df.cut=df.cut.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories = cut_Kategoriler,ordered=True))
print(df.head())
sns.catplot(x="cut",y="price",data=df)
sns.barplot(x="cut",y="price",hue="color",data=df)
```

I want create two plots. But these plots overflap. How can i separate the graphics in the last two lines?

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: plots on top of each other. How can I separate

Comment: Please describe your problem in your post (not the comments). You can [edit] and add information there. Explain which data and how you want to separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then add `plt.show()` after each of the two plots.

The modified code is added below:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Import Matplotlib
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

diamonds = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")

df=diamonds.copy()
cut_Kategoriler=["Fair","Good","Very Good","Premium","Ideal"]

df.cut=df.cut.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories = cut_Kategoriler,ordered=True))

print(df.head())

sns.catplot(x="cut",y="price",data=df)
plt.show() # Display the first plot
sns.barplot(x="cut",y="price",hue="color",data=df)
plt.show() # Display the second plot
```